# Should we load different language files for Front End and Backend in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, translation

I will write a theme which will be made available in a few languages other than English. My text domain is **my-theme**. My question is -

Should we load two separate language files - one for the front-end and another for the back-end theme options? If so, should I give a text domain like **my-theme-options**?

Or, is it okay to keep all the translations (*both for front and backend*) in one .pot file and load a single text-domain like **my-theme**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Back end is translated globally by wp.org team, so you don't need to worry with that part (unless your language isn't fully translated, in which case you can contribute with the translation :)). Now if you're adding CPTs, it's best to create a plugin, and then translate it using .po file. Usually all the translatable strings in the theme and plugins are scanned (with the POEditor for instance), so there is no separation necessary.
Also the gettext will just scan the .mo file and translate any string that is a match, no matter where in the app :)

Comment: Yes. that's my question. As said, I will have a dedicated Theme Options page with many fields. Of course they won't be translated by default by WP. As an author I must do this. So, should I load a separate pot file and a text domain for the admin area or keep all translations in one text domain.

Comment: No, just keep everything in the same domain, since it's the one theme :)

Comment: Oh, and a quick question, is this theme for wordpress.org or? Because custom options page isn't allowed there

Comment: @dingo_d Thanks for the clarification. No, mine won't be in the WP repository.

Comment: Ok, then just go ahead and create away :D